# python - matplot lib sub-plot grid: where to insert row/column arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm trying to display the topic extraction results of an LDA text analysis across several data sets in the form of a matplotlib subplot.

Here's where I'm at:

I think my issue is my unfamiliarity with matplotlib. I have done all my number crunching ahead of time so that I can focus on how to plot the data:

```
top_words_master = []
top_weights_master = []
for i in range(len(tf_list)):
    tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(tf_list[i])
    lda.fit(tf)
    n_top_words = 20
    tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
    top_features_ind = lda.components_[0].argsort()[: -n_top_words - 1 : -1]
    top_features = [tf_feature_names[i] for i in top_features_ind]
    weights = lda.components_[0][top_features_ind]
    top_words_master.append(top_features)
    top_weights_master.append(weights)
```

This gives me my words and my weights (the x axis values) to make my sub-plot matrix of row/bar charts.

My attempt to construct this via matplot lib:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 5, figsize=(30, 15), sharex=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
fig.suptitle("Topics in LDA Model", fontsize=18, y=0.95)
axes = axes.flatten()
for i in range(len(tf_list)):

    ax = axes[i]
    ax.barh(top_words_master[i], top_weights_master[i], height=0.7)
    ax.set_title(topic_map[f"Topic {i +1}"], fontdict={"fontsize": 30})
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="major", labelsize=20)
    for j in "top right left".split():
        ax.spines[j].set_visible(False)
    fig.suptitle("Topics in LDA Model", fontsize=40)

    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90, bottom=0.05, wspace=0.90, hspace=0.3)
    plt.show()
```

However, it only showed one, the first one. For the remaining 6 data sets it just printed:

```
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes> <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes> <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes> <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes> <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

### Question

I've been at this for days. I feel I'm close, but this kind of result is really puzzling me, anyone have a solution or able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where does `top_word_comparison` comes from, is it a self-defined function? If so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @FarhoodET It was originally `plot_top_words` in the documentation example, but I changed it to `top_word_comparison` to reflect the function's new purpose. I think the issue is still that it is drawing and erasing rather than storing a sub-plot, moving to next sub-plot and then plotting once it's iterated over all my model fits. If that makes sense. Trying to explain without being too confusing, but text-analysis has so much jargon. I apologize if parts aren't clear.

Comment: If you create the figure once, with 2 rows and 5 columns, you can get the i'th row j'th column axes / subplot with ax = axes[i][j]. Then do all the plotting using ax.

Comment: If you want to use all 10 of the axes inside top_word_comparison, then pass in axes instead of axes[i]. But I'm not clear on how your data is organized. If you're going to loop for j in range(2), then you need to use j somewhere in the loop. Otherwise, you're just doing the same thing twice.

Comment: @Alex You're right, just noticed there are clones in the subplots. The data is structured as a list (seven elements long). So ideally, after iterating over it all, it would fill the first row of five then have three empty spaces in the second row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood from your question, your problem is to get the right indices for your subplots.

In your case, you have an array `range(len(tf_list))` to index your data, some data (e.g. `top_words_master[i]`) to plot, and a figure with 10 subplots (rows=2,cols=5). For example, if you want to plot the 7th item (i=6) of your data, the indices of `ax` would be `axes[1,1]`.

In order to get the correct indices for the subplot axes, you can use [numpy.unravel_index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html). And, of course, you should not `flatten` your `axes`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# dummy function
my_func = lambda x: np.random.random(x)
x_max = 100

# fig properties
rows = 2
cols = 5
fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows,cols,figsize=(30, 15), sharex=True)

for i in range(rows*cols):
    ax_i = np.unravel_index(i,(rows,cols))
    
    axes[ax_i[0],ax_i[1]].barh(np.arange(x_max),my_func(x_max), height=0.7)

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

You should create the figure first:

```
def top_word_comparison(axes, model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        top_features_ind = topic.argsort()[: -n_top_words - 1 : -1]
        top_features = [feature_names[i] for i in top_features_ind]
        weights = topic[top_features_ind]

        ax = axes[topic_idx]
        ax.barh(top_features, weights, height=0.7)
        ax.set_title(topic_map[f"Topic {topic_idx +1}"], fontdict={"fontsize": 30})
        ax.invert_yaxis()
        ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="major", labelsize=20)
        for i in "top right left".split():
            ax.spines[i].set_visible(False)

tf_list = [cm_array, xb_array]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(tf_list), 5, figsize=(30, 15), sharex=True)
fig.suptitle("Topics in LDA model", fontsize=40)

for i in range(enumerate(tf_list)):
    tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(tf_list[i])
    n_components = 1
    lda.fit(tf)
    n_top_words = 20
    tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
    top_word_comparison(axes[i], lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90, bottom=0.05, wspace=0.90, hspace=0.3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Definitely getting close, thanks. Seems like everything was appended to the first column. Maybe we need to include the `j` column logic somewhere? ( I set axes to `plt.subplots(2,5)...` ) just because I want to keep 2x5 layout. Won't have more than 10; just want them appended left to right then bottom row, left to right.